Add N suffix to duplicated items
Input:
apple.LONG_UUID.BLAH.BLAH
orange
apple.ANOTHER_UUID
chair.01.AB

Wanted output:
apple 1
orange
apple 2
chair

I started by extracting substring before dot with
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "${line%%.*}"
done <<< "$list"

That gave me:
apple
orange
apple
chair

Not sure how to proceed from that, keep in mind real list is way longer and always unique the only thing that persist is that important part of item is before dot if dot is present.

As you don't want e.g. orange 1, you need more than just one pass, because only in the end you will know for sure if a given prefix had just one occurrence or not. I'd suggest using awk for the entire process.

@pmf awk looks like black magic to me. Could you give me a start?

Awk is a small language, you can easily pick up the basics in fifteen minutes and probably solve this problem in less than an hour.

Here's an approach using awk.
-F . sets the dot as field separator, which gives access to the desired prefix in $1. In the iteration line, three arrays are populated: a gets the prefix, b its current occurrence, both indexed by line (record) number NR, while c aggregates the highest number of occurrences for each prefix. After the last input line (END), we iterate over the line numbers (from 1 to the final NR), emitting the actual items of a (the prefix), followed by a space and the according occurrence number (from b) if the highest count (from c) for that prefix is greater than 1.
awk -F . '{ a[NR]=$1; b[NR]=++c[$1] }
  END { for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) print a[i] (c[a[i]] > 1? " " b[i]: "") }
' input.txt

apple 1
orange
apple 2
chair


This has to be a 2-step process: you don't know if there are duplicates until you read the whole list.
In bash:
words=()
declare -A count=() count2=()

while IFS=. read -r word _; do
    words+=("$word")
    count[$word]=$(( count[$word] + 1 ))
done <<<"$list"

for word in "${words[@]}"; do
    if (( count[$word] == 1 )); then
        echo "$word"
    else
        count2[$word]=$(( count2[$word] + 1 ))
        echo "$word ${count2[$word]}"
    fi
done

apple 1
orange
apple 2
chair

